# How to display EditText on marker InfoWindow on map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-edittext, google-maps-markers, infowindow

I am trying to display EditText(To take input from user and perform some operation).

[image]

In the above image, I want the EditText control to be displayed in the Hello world info window. Please suggest me any Idea, how to do this. Is it possible to insert UI controls on info window.

Please help!! Any help will be appreciated!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can put any layout to infoWindow. Please follow this [tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/customizing-infowindow-contents-in-google-map-android-api-v2-using-infowindowadapter/)